# Why the script is not rotating my sphere object?

Tags: c#, unity-game-engine

Well, I am new to unity 3d and C sharp. I was trying a script to rotate my spehere object . But it's not working.

I was following a youtube video. This code worked for him. But in my case it is not working.

I added the transform object.

```
using UnityEngine;
using System.Collections;

public class cubescript : MonoBehaviour {
    public Transform sphereTransform;

    // Use this for initialization
    void Start () {
        sphereTransform.parent = transform;


    }

    // Update is called once per frame
    void Update () {
        transform.eulerAngles = new Vector3 (0, 180*Time.deltaTime, 0);
    }
}
```

It's kind of working but stuck at 2.981877-3 Y rotation .. And not rotating around the cube..

Comment: You want to rotate the sphere around a cube?

Comment: Did you attached this script to the  cube?

Comment: yeah i did @MiladQasemi

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The problem is that you are trying to rotate, but `eulerAngles` only sets to ABSOLUTE angles (if you want to add angles to the current frame angle, you will use `Rotate`).

So, if you use `transform.eulerAngles` you will be all the frames setting the angle change to what `180 * Time.deltaTime` returns, that will depend on how many FPS you are running, thats why you get constant number.

If you use `transform.Rotate` it will add the new angle change to the current angle frame. Say that you want to increment by 10 degress, so frame 1 = (0,0,0), frame 2 = (0,10,0), frame 3 = (0,20,0).

In `eulerAngles` you will get all the time (0,10,0), because it sets ABSOLUTE angle, `Rotate` adds to the current angle what you want.

Change this

```
transform.eulerAngles = new Vector3 (0, 180*Time.deltaTime, 0);
```

To this

```
transform.Rotate(new Vector3 (0, 180*Time.deltaTime, 0));
```

This is the official Unity Documentation for [eulerAngle](https://docs.unity3d.com/ScriptReference/Transform-eulerAngles.html) and [Rotate](https://docs.unity3d.com/ScriptReference/Transform.Rotate.html)

Answer (score 0):

As said in another answer, when you set `transform.eulerAngles`, you are setting an absolute rotation. You can use `transform.Rotate()` but you can also use `Time.time` to ensure that you get linear rotation: `transform.eulerAngles = new Vector3(0, 180*Time.time, 0);`

Comment: It would be better if you edited the existing answer with your addition!